# Trying to build Risk style game in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have been trying to build my skills in Python and am trying to create a risk style game.

I am not far in to it at the moment as I am trying to get to grips with classes and Tkinter.

My first trial is to create a series of buttons to take the place of the different countries. I then want these buttons to update the amount of armies on the country when they are clicked.

So far I have been able to get the map to generate from the class I have created and the buttons are clickable. When a button is clicked it updates the amount of armies but always for the last button.

How do I get it so that the button I click updates and not the last one?

Have I gone about this in entirely the wrong way?

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class territory:
   def __init__ (self, country, player = "1", current_armies = 0, x=0, y=0):
        self.country = country
        self.current_armies = current_armies
        self.player = player
        self.y = y
        self.x = x

    def get_armies(self):
        print(self.country + " has " + str( self.current_armies)+ " armies.")

    def add_armies (self, armies):
        self.current_armies += armies

    def roll_dice (self, dice=1):
        rolls = []
        for i in range(0, dice):
            rolls.append(random.randint(1,6))
        rolls.sort()
        rolls.reverse()
        print (self.country + " has rolled " + str(rolls))
        return rolls

    def owner(self):
        print (self.country + " is owned by " + self.player)

    def get_country(self):
        print(country)

    def button (self):
        Button(window, text = territories[0].current_armies, width = 10, command =        click1(territories, 0)).grid(row=y,column=x)

window = Tk()

def create_territories():
    countries = ["UK", "GER", "SPA", "RUS"]
    terr_pos = [[1,0],[2,0],[1,5],[4,1]]
    sta_arm = [1,1,1,1]
    terr = []
    player = "1"
    for i in range(len(countries)):

        terr.append(territory(countries[i],player, sta_arm [i] , terr_pos[i][0],terr_pos[i][1]))
        if player == "1":
            player = "2"
        else:
            player = "1"
    return terr

def click1(territory, i):
    territory[i].current_armies += 1
    build_board(territory)


def build_board(territories):
     for i in range(0,4):
        Button(window, text = territories[i].country+"\n"+str(territories[i].current_armies), width = 10, command = lambda: click1(territories, i)).grid(row=territories[i].y,column=territories[i].x)

territories = create_territories()




window.title ("Domination")
create_territories()
build_board(territories)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `def button(self):...` you are always referencing `territories[0]`:

> ```
> Button(window, text=territories[0].current_armies,... command=click1(territories, 0)...
> ```

As such, you are always using the first territory as your reference, so you ought to initialize each territory with its index in `territories[]` so you can pass that into your `Button` constructor.

---

On your question of "entirely the wrong way," I'd personally send that question over to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), since that's more of their domain (we fix broken code, they address smelly code), though there is significant overlap. We do prefer one question per question, however, and "is this whole thing wrong?" is a little broad for StackOverflow.